# Problem using Identity in ASP.NET Core API [RESOLVED]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

Good afternoon, I am trying to use Identity in my API, but I have some error that I believe is dependency injection.

I did all the necessary configuration, connected with the database, generated the Migrations, but when I try to inject as classes SignInManager and UserManager from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity in my Controller, I'm taking an error of ArgumentNullException in Startup, as well as the image below.

[image: ArgumentNullException]

The error of understanding that the application is unable to access the string within appsettings, however to apply Migrations is working.

If I remove SignInManager and UserManager from the Controller the error will stop. Following implementations:

Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

AppDbContext:

```
namespace Identity.API.Data
{
  public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
  {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : 
    base(options) {}
  }
}
```

appsettings:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":
    "Server= (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDb;
      Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Identity.API.Controllers
{
   [ApiController]
   [Route("auth")]
   public class AuthController : Controller
   {
     public readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager;
     public readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager;

     public AuthController(
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
     {
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        UserManager = userManager;
     }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "IT WORKS";
    }
  }
}
```

[EDIT]: If pass the direct connection string, it gives the same problem, for example: options.UseSqlServer("Server= (localdb)...")

[EDIT2]: I found the problem, the error is only occurring when using the vscode debugger, it's probably just the launch.json configuration.

Comment: Make sure that your environment-specific configuration includes the connection string, or that your environment points to a config file with that connection string.

Comment: Please check the value of `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` runtime

Comment: Where does your configuration object come from ?
Do you initialize it in your Startup constructor ?

Comment: If pass the direct connection string, it gives the same problem, for example:  options.UseSqlServer("Server= (localdb)...").

Comment: I found the problem, the error is only occurring when using the vscode debugger, it's probably just the launch.json configuration.